# Fastest way to count number of occurrences in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What is the fastest way to compute the number of occurrences of elements within a Pandas series?

My current fastest solution involves `.groupby(columnname).size()`.  Is there anything faster within Pandas?  E.g. I want something like the following:

```
In [42]: df = DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'a'])

In [43]: df.groupby(0).size()
Out[43]: 
0
a    2
b    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Worrying about optimizations on this level seems like a waste of time, but you could try `value_counts`: it should have less overhead.

Answer (score 3):

The `value_counts()` function in pandas does this exactly.

Use that function on the column you want.
i.e.

```
df['column_i_want'].value_counts()
```